# APACHE POI - cloneStyleFrom doesn't copy BorderStyle

Tags: java, apache, excel, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

I've a problem with the library apache poi, i want to copy the style of a cell and to do this i use the function cloneStyleFrom() and all works good except the copy of borders style. I don't understand if is my mistake or if this function doesn't implements the copy of the borders style.

This is my code:

```
int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
if (newCellStyle == null) {
    newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
    styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
}
    newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
```

Someone can help me? Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: What version of POI you're using?

Comment: What's about the style of the "oldCell"? It was created programmatically, or it is contained in a workbook that was created with MS Excel? If it was created programmatically can you post that code?

Comment: The oldCell is contained in a workbook that was created in MS Excel 2007. On the workbook that contains the old cell i read only.

Comment: I also failed to clone style from one book to another. It seems like POI's bug. I think you should find a workaround, for example, try to copy style manually.